# htaccess file: Prevent redirecting addon domain pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a main ssl domain https://www.a.com and a normal addon domain http://www.b.com on the same server. I use this .htaccess rule for a.com to redirect an old page in that website to a new one:

```
Redirect permanent /my_page.php /my_page
```

It works just fine. When i access **a.com/my_page.php** it redirects to **a.com/my_page**. The problem is that the addon domain b.com has the same page name inside its folder, so when i access **b.com/my_page.php** it also redirects to **b.com/my_page**. I need to prevent this redirection for the addon domain.

*Note*: *I have tried to use this redirection rule instead but it didn't work at all:*

```
RewriteRule https://www.a.com/my_page.php https://www.a.com/my_page
```

And this one too didn't work:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^a.com/my_page.php$ https://www.a.com/my_page
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some reading and studying i was able to fix this using the RewriteRule instead. Here's the new code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*a.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/my_page\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.a.com/my_page [L,R=301]
```